# robocopy a specific directory and its contents but not the files on the same directory-depth

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, robocopy

I have a folder structure like this:

```
    R:\TOPFOLDER
├───Folder_1
│   │   other File.txt
│   │
│   ├───!Downloads
│   └───other_Folder
├───Folder_2
│   │   other File.txt
│   │
│   ├───!Downloads
│   └───other_Folder
├───Folder_3
│   │   other File.txt
│   │
│   ├───!Downloads
│   └───other_Folder
├───Folder_4
│   │   other File.txt
│   │
│   ├───!Downloads
│   └───other_Folder
└───Folder_5
    │   other File (2).txt
    │   other File.txt
    │
    ├───!Downloads
    └───other_Folder
```

I want to keep the folder structure intact. Every folder (`Folder_1 - Folder_n`) may contain either additional files and/or additional subdirectories. I want to leave them on drive `R:`. I only want to **copy the `!Downloads` directory and its contents to E:\ .**

So the result would be:

```
    E:\TOPFOLDER
├───Folder_1
│   └───!Downloads
├───Folder_2
│   └───!Downloads
├───Folder_3
│   └───!Downloads
├───Folder_4
│   └───!Downloads
└───Folder_5
    └───!Downloads
```

I tried to use a robocopy command: `robocopy /s R:\FolderTOP\*\!Downloads E:\FolderTOP\` thinking the wildcard would stand for every subdir namend `Folder_1 - Folder_n` in the example, but I get an error.

Comment: alternatively I tried with my limited knowledge in PowerShell and I got to the point where I have a list of the directories. Now how could I copy the directories? `gci R:\TopFOlder !Downloads -Recurse | select fullname
Copy-Item -Destination E:\TopFolder`

Comment: `gci 'R:\TopFolder\*\!Downloads' -Recurse | select fullname`  - I have the list of files, how do I copy these to `E:\TofFolder\*\!Downloads` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know powershell very well but I can do a batch file that can do it.

The only thing you have to change is the Source and Destiny variables:

Set Source=%userprofile%\desktop\Source

Set Destiny=%userprofile%\desktop\Destiny

---

Updated...31/07/2021

```
@echo off

:: Copy the contents of folders called "!Downloads" in the Source only
chcp 65001 > nul

Set Source=%userprofile%\desktop\Source
Set Destiny=%userprofile%\desktop\Destiny
Set "SWord=!Downloads"

if /i not "%Source:~-1%"=="\" set "Source=%Source%\"
if /i not "%Destiny:~-1%"=="\" set "Destiny=%Destiny%\"

pushd "%Source%"
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /ad /b *%SWord%*') do (                                                                                                                 
                                                        call :CopyFiles "%%~Fa"                                                                                                                   
                                                       )
exit

:CopyFiles
set "Folder=%~1"
Call set "Folder=%%Folder:%Source%=%%"
xcopy "%Folder%" "%Destiny%%Folder%\" /h /s /r /y /i /q
goto :EOF
```

Comment: before I try this, `SWord` you have written Downloads, but it is `!Downloads` is that exclamation mark a problem or why have you omitted it?

Comment: Ok I just tried it, replacing `Downloads`in `SWord` with `!Downloads` - but the output is File not Found... - I renamed one folder to `Downloads` and it did copy this one, even though I have changed the SWord. So the exclamation mark constitutes an issue

Comment: A goole Search for SWord yields only entries for the weapon, sword... I would like to learn about SWord but it seems a hidden ressource

Comment: Sword is just a variable that I named "SWord" for "Searched Word" but It could be any name you want. I didn't pay close attention about "!Downloads" I thouht it was only "Downloads"...The "!" could actually represent a problem since I enabled "DelayedExpansion" which enbles words with like "!Folder!" to be seen as a variable...I'll change the code to make it work with "!" soon.

Comment: Ok, try it now I fixed it

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been trying all afternoon but I haven't succeeded. I don't know that much about the cmd/batch. The reason I opened the question with that was because I thought that's a pretty easy task but looking at your code it seems awfully complicated for such a seemingls "trivial" thing to do?

Comment: Actually that is not one of the batches that uses a lot of code, but I guess with powershel one would use less lines.

Comment: I left the copy-job unattended. At some point it stopped with the message `Maximum setlocal recursion level reached.
File not found - Downloads`

Comment: I have never heard from that error, how many "!Downloads" do you have? I've updated my answer again (without using "DalayedExtension" can you test again?

Comment: I have 56 of these folders in total, and the error occurred in every instance after 15 items.